# How to access all elements in class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I access elements in class `imagecontainerbox`? I want to access `previewimage1`, `previewimage2` and every this type of element.

I tried `nth-child` but it is not working. It gives me list of elements in preview div not what I want:

```
$('.imagecontainerbox:nth-child(0) img').attr(src);
$('preview').children('.imagecontainerbox:nth-child(0) img').attr(src);
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="preview" style="">

  <span id="text0"></span>
  <div id="previewimage1" class="imagecontainerbox" style="position:relative;padding:5px;margin:5px;width:515px;">
    <img src="undefined" class="realimage" id="image1" height="undefined" width="undefined" style="position:relative ;z-index:2px; border:5px solid #f8f8f8;border-radius:5px;padding:2px;">
    <img src="image/list/cancel1.png" style="float:right;padding:5px;position:absolute;top:10px;left:NaNpx;z-index: 1;" onclick="removeimage(this)">
  </div>

  <span id="text1">   </span>
  <span id="text2">   </span>
  <span id="text3">   </span>

  <div id="previewimage4" class="imagecontainerbox" style="position:relative;padding:5px;margin:5px;width:515px;">
    <img src="tempimage/MosLake1365324410.jpg" class="realimage" id="image4" height="666.66666666667" width="500" style="position:relative ;z-index:2px; border:5px solid #f8f8f8;border-radius:5px;padding:2px;">
    <img src="image/list/cancel1.png" style="float:right;padding:5px;position:absolute;top:10px;left:490px;z-index: 1;" onclick="removeimage(this)">
  </div>
  <span id="text4">   </span>

  <div id="previewimage5" class="imagecontainerbox" style="position:relative;padding:5px;margin:5px;width:515px;">
    <img src="tempimage/MosLake1365324416.jpg" class="realimage" id="image5" height="375" width="500" style="position:relative ;z-index:2px; border:5px solid #f8f8f8;border-radius:5px;padding:2px;">
    <img src="image/list/cancel1.png" style="float:right;padding:5px;position:absolute;top:10px;left:490px;z-index: 1;" onclick="removeimage(this)">
  </div>
  <span id="text5">   </span>

  <div id="previewimage6" class="imagecontainerbox" style="position:relative;padding:5px;margin:5px;width:515px;">
    <img src="tempimage/MosLake1365324421.jpg" class="realimage" id="image6" height="666.66666666667" width="500" style="position:relative ;z-index:2px; border:5px solid #f8f8f8;border-radius:5px;padding:2px;">
    <img src="image/list/cancel1.png" style="float:right;padding:5px;position:absolute;top:10px;left:490px;z-index: 1;" onclick="removeimage(this)">
  </div>
  <span id="text6">   </span>

  <div id="previewimage7" class="imagecontainerbox" style="position:relative;padding:5px;margin:5px;width:515px;">
    <img src="tempimage/MosLake1365324426.jpg" class="realimage" id="image7" height="375" width="500" style="position:relative ;z-index:2px; border:5px solid #f8f8f8;border-radius:5px;padding:2px;">
    <img src="image/list/cancel1.png" style="float:right;padding:5px;position:absolute;top:10px;left:490px;z-index: 1;" onclick="removeimage(this)">
  </div>
  <span id="text7">   </span>

  <div id="previewimage8" class="imagecontainerbox" style="position:relative;padding:5px;margin:5px;width:515px;">
    <img src="tempimage/MosLake1365324431.jpg" class="realimage" id="image8" height="666.66666666667" width="500" style="position:relative ;z-index:2px; border:5px solid #f8f8f8;border-radius:5px;padding:2px;">
    <img src="image/list/cancel1.png" style="float:right;padding:5px;position:absolute;top:10px;left:490px;z-index: 1;" onclick="removeimage(this)">
  </div>
  <span id="text8">   </span>

  <div id="previewimage9" class="imagecontainerbox" style="position:relative;padding:5px;margin:5px;width:515px;">
    <img src="tempimage/MosLake1365324440.jpg" class="realimage" id="image9" height="666.66666666667" width="500" style="position:relative ;z-index:2px; border:5px solid #f8f8f8;border-radius:5px;padding:2px;">
    <img src="image/list/cancel1.png" style="float:right;padding:5px;position:absolute;top:10px;left:490px;z-index: 1;" onclick="removeimage(this)">
  </div>
  <span id="text9">  asd</span>
</div>
```

I am using this jQuery:

```
var image = $('#preview').children('.imagecontainerbox').length;
var imagesrc = $('#preview  .imagecontainerbox:nth-child('+image+') img').attr('src');

for(var i = 1; i <= image; i++) {

  if($(it).siblings('.realimage').attr('src') == $('.imagecontainerbox:nth-child('+i+')   img').attr('src')) {
    num = i;
    var p = $('#preview').children('.imagecontainerbox:nth-child('+i+')').attr('id');
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you *want*? Get all `src` attributes of images within a `imagecontainerbox` div?

Comment: `src` is not defined. Use quote around them if you want the value of the `src` attribute `.attr("src")`

Comment: no... i don't want to get src.... i want the imagecontainer box's attribute "id" ..... means i have put a cancel image on it.... ewhen i press cancel image .... it should cancel whole div....

Comment: Deepka kamat thats not a problem.... that will be solved bt main prob i want to get id of the imagecontainerbox ... in which i mouseover or click....

Comment: explain full objective of your code. You probably don't need the ID at all

Comment: i have a cancel button image on the image.... when it clicked it removes the div box containing it.... but i want the div number in which the image exist because i have to use this number in another function "num" ... that num will help me to delete the other data of this image in file.... whiche has id which includes this "num"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `removeimage()` method you can get the ID of the wrapping `imagecontainerbox` element using `parent()` or `closest()`

```
function removeimage( element){
   alert( $(element).parent().attr('id') );

       /* or */
    alert( $(element).closest('.imagecontainerbox').attr('id') );  

}
```

Most of the code shown  makes little sense so still not entirely clear what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Just use [strarts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector:

```
$("div[id^='previewimage'])
```

This selector will selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value beginning exactly with a given string which is `previewimage` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
$('#preview > .imagecontainerbox').each(function(){
    var $container = $(this);
    var containerID = $container.attr('id');
})
```

This way u can get the id of all the elements of that class.